# How do I automate a right click in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to automate simulation of a right click to open the context menu. Once the menu is open, select the selected action/shortcut available.

I know how to open:

```
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}");
```

Or using the [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) automation language (BASIC like):

```
  ;--on right click event
    MouseClick("right")
    $count = 1
    Do
        Send("{DOWN}")
        $count = $count + 1  

    Until $count > 7
    Send("{ENTER}")
    ;---select shortcut
    WinWaitActive("xxxxk")

    ;----doing execution from the 3rd program
    ControlSend("xxxxx",  "", "Edit2", "123ABC")
    Sleep(500)
    ControlSend("xxxxx",  "", "Edit3", "123ABC")
    Sleep(500)
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Sleep(500)

    WinClose("xxxxx")
    WinWaitActive("xxxxx", "Close")
    Send("{ENTER}")
```

Can I have something like this in VBScript? Too messy, I think.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is in your question

```
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}");
```

once the right click menu is open send another key 's' (in most cases 's' is used to select/select all)

```
shell.Sendkeys  "s"
```

and you're done :)

here goes the complete code

```
shell.Sendkeys  ("+{F10}")
shell.Sendkeys  "s"
```

the above code should work in VBScript right click automation,

i'd also like to mention that Right-Click in a title bar is equivalent to ALT+SPACE, so if you want to right click on the title bar by vbscript i'll advice you to send `ALT+SPACE` instead

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right click on what?

If you are talking about files/folders (in Windows Explorer), you can do it with shell automation: [DoIt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774170(VS.85).aspx) or [InvokeVerb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787816(VS.85).aspx)